# In JComponent only one object is showing

Tags: java, jcomponent, graphic

Hey guys, sorry I'm kind of new to programming, but I had a small problem with my BarChart program. Everything seems to be running ok. What I want to do is enter a few integers and then have my program generate images to represent the forms on data. If I enter a few numbers, only one image appears. Please help me out!

PS. I know that I could just have a paintcomponent method within my BarChart class, but my professor specifically wanted only these two methods in the class.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BarChartTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {

      BarChartPaintComponent component = new BarChartPaintComponent();
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      BarChart test = new BarChart();
      System.out.println("Enter the Values you wish to use ( >0 ). Press -1 on an    empty line to stop");
      Boolean flag = false;
      while(!flag)
      {
           double numbers = in.nextDouble();
           if(numbers == -1)
           flag = true;
           else if(numbers<-1)
           System.out.println("You have typed in invalid number");
           else
           component.add(numbers);
     }
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setSize(300, 300);
      frame.setTitle("A Bar Graph");
      frame.add(component);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BarChart extends JComponent
{
private ArrayList<Double> list;
private double value;
private int i;

public BarChart()
{

    list = new ArrayList<Double>();
}


public void add(double value)
{
    list.add(i, value);
    i++;
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    Double greatest = list.get(0);
    Double least;
    for(int j =1;j<list.size();j++)
    {
        if(list.get(j)> greatest)
        greatest = list.get(j);
        else
        least = list.get(j);
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        int x = 10;
        int width = 20;
        double barNumber = list.get(i);
        if(barNumber == greatest){
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x,0,width,300));
        }
        else
        {
            g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
             g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x,0,width, barNumber));
         }

        x +=20;

    }



}
}

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;


public class BarChartPaintComponent extends BarChart
{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    this.draw(g);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int x = 10;
```

This should be moved out of the for loop. It is getting initialized to same value everytime hence all bars are drawn at same place.

If you just added `System.out.println(x);` inside your for loop the problem would have been obvious.

Comment: Thank you!! I feel so stupid for not noticing this. Appreciate it